# Scheme length of list using tailrecursion

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

I have been trying to find the length of a list using scheme using tail recursion and so far, I have this

```
(define num-els2
  (lambda(xs)
    mynum xs 0))

(define mynum
  (lambda (xs empt)
    (if (empty? xs)
        empt
        (mynum (rest xs) (+ empt 1)))))
```

but it keeps giving me 0. I think for some reason it does not increment my return value. So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the parentheses in the `num-els2` procedure, nothing serious. Basically, you are not correctly calling the `mynum` helper procedure, and the procedure is always returning `0`, because that's the last expression in the body. Here, this should fix it:

```
(define num-els2
  (lambda(xs)
    (mynum xs 0))) ; notice the opening bracket in this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Scheme provides a named let for this:

```
(define (list-length list)
  (let loop ((list list)
             (length 0))
    (if (null? list)
        length
        (loop (cdr list) (+ length 1)))))
```

It is part of the standard since R2RS (1985). Earlier it has been called "iterate".

The named let specification is part of the section [Iterations](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.4).